# How to reuse uibarbutton in navigation bar when views are pushed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

What is the best approach for when you want the same buttons (and their functionality) to appear in the navigation bar of a navigation controller when views are pushed and popped. For example, in my app I want a 'user settings' button to appear in the navigation bar regardless of the view that is currently at the top of the stack. When the button is tapped a popover appears which displays a list of specific settings. Do I have to set up this functionality for each view that can appear in the stack? Or is there a way to set it up once and allow it to appear for all the views in the stack?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to subclass UIViewController. Have all the views that need to have this behavior inherit from the subclass.